# GcmBroadcastReceiver receiving message twice

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, pubnub

I am working with `PubNub` to send and receive messages but I am having a weird issue with my Android implementation. The following is executed twice every time I receive a notification on the device:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       // Triggered twice
    }
}
```

I have checked that the message is only sent once and all messages only arrive once on my iOS implementation. Can someone help me figure out why this happens?

Comment: Is your pushnotification sent from php code or API?

Comment: I am using a third party to send the notifications, a publish/subscribe service from PubNub. Since they arrive perfectly on iOS I am fairly certain the issue is not with where they are sent from, but rather the way they arrive on the Android device.

Comment: Ya I know about the PubNub.My Question is that. for e.g. Assume this scenario.User sending a request to some xyz API of your project and that API call pubnub service to send Push Notificaiton to other devices. So i am talking about this this is your app call some api and that api call pubnub service is it so?

Comment: Ah okay. No I send the notifications directly from the app to PubNub with the appropriate payloads for APNs and GCM (following the guides here: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/android-java/mobile-gateway#Publishing_to_GCM). No API.

Comment: You face this issue because you get the pushnotification from pubnub and also get the payload so that's why you receive the notificaiton twice.Try to print using log in onReceive method how many times you got the payload.

Comment: Oh okay I see that now, I just tried running it to check the payload. How can I best make sure to not get both?

Comment: you will get both, but you can check to see if you have already received it from the other channel and then discard the second one.

Comment: Simply ignore (don't display) the GCM if the app is in foreground.